# Are there weak spots on any Borderlands 3 vehicles that can be attacked without needing to use elemental damage?

Tags: borderlands-3

Obviously different guns deal different amounts of damage and thus some guns are more effective against vehicles than others, but is there one or more weak spots for each of the vehicles, similar to how you can deal critical damage to enemies?

The [Borderlands wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_damage) states that Corrosion is great against armored enemies, vehicles, and turrets:

> Corrosive damage is best used against armored enemies ... or any vehicle or turret.

But is it possible to deal additional damage to vehicles without the use of elemental damage?

Comment: This quote is Borderlands 1 related. Are all B3 vehicles have armor? Honestly, vehicles never posses enough threat (as opposed to previous games, where they could oneshot by ramming), since you can just hijack. Or simply avoid: if you met a vehicle, then you are riding one as well.

Answer (score 2):

The only "weakspot" a vehicle has are the enemies on the vehicle. Once you take the driver and passengers, the vehicle is in fact not doing anything anymore.

To actually destroy the vehicle the fastest, the only option you have is to use weapons/builds that shred through armor.